# Find the co-efficient of $x^3y^3zw^2$ in the expression of $(x-y+2z-2w)^9$.

Tags: binomial-theorem

> Find the co-efficient of $x^3y^3zw^2$ in the expression of $(x-y+2z-2w)^9$.

I have clearly understood how to use the bin theorem for $(a+b)^n$, but am unable to extend the theorem to $4$ terms .

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For four terms, there is something called the multinomial expansion. It actually follows from the multinomial expansion that the answer is $\frac{9!}{1!2!3!3!} = 5040$ (I think I know the woman in your profile picture)

Comment: Haha , shes an Indian actress , Prachi Desai ! That is a very old picture though . Btw , is there some general formula for this multinomial thing you are talking about ?

Answer (score 2):

We have $9$ copies of $x-y+2z-2w$. We need to choose $3$ factors for the $x^3$, $3$ factors for the $(-y)^3$, and $1$ factor for the $(2z)$; the remaining two factors will be for the $(-2w)^2$. This produces a term $-8 x^3 y^3 z w^2$.

It remains to count how many ways to make the choices above. This is $\binom{9}{3} \binom{6}{3} \binom{3}{1} = \frac{9!}{3!3!1!2!} = 7! = 5040$. So the coefficient is $5040 \cdot (-8) = -40320$.

Comment: OMG , yes ! That makes sense! Silly me , I should have just remembered to apply the basics of the binomial theorem . but wait , wont it be -40320 , Since the co eff of (-y) cube will leave us -1 ? Only confirming. Anyway , I have understood this concept better now , Im sure ill ace my coming exams on the binomial theory . Thanks a ton mate !

Comment: @NikhilKapoor Yes you're right, sorry. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to apply the binomial theorem    *iteratively*. We focus on one term and keep the other terms together. This way we reduce the number of terms step by step by one, till we have only two left at the end.

To keep the calculations manageable it is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^j]$ to select the coefficient of $x^j$ of a polynomial or series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[x^j](x+y+z)^n&=[x^j]\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k(y+z)^{n-k}\\
&=\binom{n}{j}(y+z)^{n-j}\\
\end{align*}

> Using this technique we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^3y^3zw^2]&(x-y+2z-2w)^9\\
> &=[x^3y^3zw^2]\sum_{k=0}^9\binom{9}{k}x^k(-y+2z-2w)^{9-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{9}{3}[y^3zw^2](-y+2z-2w)^6\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{9}{3}[y^3zw^2]\sum_{k=0}^6\binom{6}{k}(-y)^k(2z-2w)^{6-k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}(-1)^3[zw^2](2z-2w)^3\tag{4}\\
> &=-\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}[zw^2]\sum_{k=0}^3\binom{3}{k}(2z)^k(-2w)^{3-k}\tag{5}\\
> &=-\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{1}2^1(-2)^2\tag{6}\\
> &=-84\cdot20\cdot3\cdot8\\
> &=-40320
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In  (1), (3) and (5)  we apply the binomial theorem
- In (2), (4) and (6) we select the coefficient of $x^3,y^3,z$ and $w^2$